# How do I load web-components with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, leaflet, web-component, elm

I'm using webpack 4 with elm and trying to bring in leaflet-map as a web-component. (This is desirable because elm has a virtual dom so mixing with standard JS tends to cause a fight over the controlled elements, it also reduces the usage of ports to talk to leaflet). However I'm struggling to configure webpack in such a fashion it recognises the import.

The package in question https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-map is a bower package and pretty much expects to be installed by bower, (otherwise it can't recognise polymer) so both the webpack-webcomponent-loader and polymer-loader packages seem to be ineffectual.

What I need to do is configure webpack to recognise a `require("bower_components/leaflet_map/leaflet_map.html")` or an `<link import="bower_components/leaflet_map/leaflet_map.html">` as a web component and import the relevant bundle, but this is outside of my `src` directory.

How can I configure webpack to parse and bundle this html file into my app? And how should I be referencing it?

Comment: Use `html-loader` plugin and require using `interpolate` option. Please notice that HTML imports have been removed from the web components specification v1.

Comment: Can you give an example? It doesn't seem to work, it just copies all the contents of the files into strings but never makes the component work

Comment: Then you haven't reviewed, as mentioned, the `interpolate` option.

Comment: For now I'm making this work by copying the files across using the copy file plugin, but I'd like to bundle this into one file to import into my app

Comment: @connexo actually I did, it did nothing in this case, I don't need the html transpiled into strings with requires, I need the actual contents of the html file in an html file, as this web component has been written as imports and script tags (see github link in post)

Comment: I managed to import a WebComponent into a React project with `import path/to/component.web`. I have placed a `.web` suffix to my customElements which I make sure NOT to transpile though babel. My webpack rule for js/jsx looks like this (note the exclude):
```module.exports = [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|public|\.web\.js)/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        plugins: ['@babel/transform-runtime'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
...```